# Hide trades on chart, quantity and signal labels via code tradingview/pine script

Tags: pine-script

Every time I update the code for a strategy the styles are reset which means that:

- Trades on Chart
- Signal labels
- Quantity

are reset to be displayed.

Is there a way to override that behavior so I can keep the 'Trades on Chart' hidden?

Thank you very much for help with this seemingly trivial issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, there is not a function to disable them by default. I also asked this a while back.

Answer (score 0):

I add a blank comment to the entry and exits in code. I can't hide quantities in code tho.

strategy.entry("long", strategy.long, when = longCondition, comment =' ')