# Hiding signal labels via pine script

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Is there a way to hide the signal labels directly via pine script? I know you can uncheck the box in the settings, but each time the script refreshes my hole chart is cluttered. I do want to keep the signal contents for debugging in the trade list, just want them removed from the graph.

[image]

Comment: Likely not: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69723407/hide-trades-on-chart-quantity-and-signal-labels-via-code-tradingview-pine-scrip

The feature was requested about 6 months ago: https://www.reddit.com/r/TradingView/comments/y431bt/remove_signal_labels_and_quantity_from_chart_with/

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to this. I will second it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your debugging purpose you can add it at the end of your code :

```
//delete all labels
label.new(bar_index, close)
a_allLabels = label.all
if array.size(a_allLabels) > 0
    for i = 0 to array.size(a_allLabels) - 1
        label.delete(array.get(a_allLabels, i))
```

It will delete all the labels drawn by your code.
see : https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#var_label%7Bdot%7Dall